# Clarification of cassandra documentation

Tags: cassandra

In the [documentation about indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html) we read

> Do not use an index in these situations:
>
> - On high-cardinality columns because you then query a huge volume of records for a small number of results. See Problems using a
>     high-cardinality column index below.

What is high-cardinality in more precise terms 100, 1000, more?

Answer (score 2):

This is a depends question but I can give you some guidelines. Secondary Indexes are for convenience and not speed. Finding column values may be something you need to support in your query and this will get it for you. The next question is how much slow can you tolerate. If you have a small cluster and several million partitions of data, low numbers won't create as much impact.

If you consider a ratio of unique values per row count, you want that as close to one-to-one for speed.

Comment: Could you consider this situation. A messaging service. A message has a sending_user_id (PK) and a set of receiving_user_ids (indexed). Would you consider querying for all messages sent to a user a healthy use-case? I think so because most of the time  the number of receiving_user_ids will be small.